# Automate create credentials for devices to connect AWS IOT Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I got some problems when try to use AWS IOT Core.

Suppose that I have thousands iot devices and 1 mobile app, 1 backend server.

My thought is I'll provide a common key for devices which has connect policy only, then when their fist connection with aws iot, it wil automate register new credentials with more roles like publish/subscribe.

Is that right?

I've follow some guide on aws documents like JITR but still not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> My thought is I'll provide a common key for devices which has connect policy only, then when their fist connection with aws iot, it wil automate register new credentials with more roles like publish/subscribe.

It must to register with AWS IoT via certificate signed by your own certificate(CA).

> AWS IoT allows the use of a single certificate for an unlimited number of devices to simplify testing but this pattern is strongly discouraged for production use.